# Why is my Python script not running via command line?

Tags: python

Thanks!

```
def hello(a,b):
    print "hello and that's your sum:"
    sum=a+b
    print sum
    import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
hello(sys.argv[2])
```

It does not work for me, I appreciate the help!!! 
Thanks!

Comment: My guess, you are trying to use `sys.argv` before importing it. Unindent the import and indent the function call .

Comment: calling hello with 1 argument is also high on list of suspects.

Comment: Also unless `sum` is concating strings together, you might have a hard time.

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing your error message it's hard to say exactly what the problem is, but a few things jump out:

- No indentation after if __name__ == "__main__":
- you're only passing one argument into the hello function and it requires two.
- the sys module is not visible in the scope outside the hello function.

probably more, but again, need the error output.

Here's what you might want:

```
import sys

def hello(a,b):
    print "hello and that's your sum:"
    sum=a+b
    print sum

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))
```

Answer (score 3):

- Import `sys` in **global scope**, not in the end of the function.
- Send **two arguments** into `hello`, one is not enough.
- Convert these arguments to **floats**, so they can be added as numbers.
- **Indent** properly. In python indentation *does* matter.

That should result in:

```
import sys

def hello(a, b):
    sum = a + b
    print "hello and that's your sum:", sum

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello(float(sys.argv[1]), float(sys.argv[2]))
```